# Move every file that is not a directory

Tags: bash, directory, wildcards, mv

I have a directory that I am trying to clean out that contains both files and subdirectories.  What I am trying to do is simple: move all the files into another directory, but leave all the sub-directories as they are.

I am thinking something like:

```
mv [*_but_no_dirs] ./other_directory
```

It seems like there should be a simple way to do this with wildcards `*` and regex...

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: So move all the files in a subfolder, but ignore any in the subdirectories?

Comment: @Wilf: Exactly.

Comment: In zsh, you could do `mv **/*(.) ./other_directory` - with bash you'd need to resort to external commands like `find`, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regex aren't involved here. Wildcards in bash (like most other shells) only match files based on the file names, not based on the file type or other characteristics. There is one way to match by type: adding `/` at the end of the pattern makes it only match directories or symbolic links to directories. This way, you can move directories, then move what's left, and move directories back — cumbersome but it works.

```
tmp=$(TMPDIR=.. mktemp -d)
mv -- */ "$tmp"
mv -- * other_directory/
mv "$tmp"/* .
rmdir "$tmp"
```

(that approach should be avoided if the current directory is the mount point of a filesystem, as that would mean the moving of directories away and back would have to copy all the data in there twice).

A standard way to match files by type is to call [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' other_directory/ {} +
```

(also moves symlinks, whether they point to directories or not).

In zsh, you can use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to match files by type. The `.` qualifier matches regular files; use `^/` to match all non-directories, or `-^/` to also exclude symbolic links to directories.

```
mv -- *(.) other_directory/
```

In any shell, you can simply loop.

```
for x in *; do
   if [ ! -d "$x" ]; then
     mv -- "$x" other_directory/
   fi
done
```

(does not move symlinks to directories).

Comment: The first approach could also fail if some of the directories are mount points or are not owned by you (even if you have write access to the current working directory). Also note that `mktemp` is not a standard command.

Answer (score 15):

You could use something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \( ! -type d \) -exec sh -c 'mv  "$@" MYDIR' _ {} \;
```

First we use `find` to look only within the current directoy, then we ignore directories by using `! -type d`  finally we execute `sh` and move everything to the destination dir. You might try  `{} +` at the end which will be faster.

Comment: Why do you suggest `-exec sh -c 'mv "$@" MYDIR' _ {} \;` rather than `-exec mv {} MYDIR \;`? Just to get something that can be streamlined by changing the `\;` to a `+`? You can do that with the `-exec mv -t MYDIR {} +` form.

Comment: @Scott  I had no idea about the `-t` flag. I also explained in the answer that the `+` is faster but not all `find` versions support it.  So the above code is pretty much compatible with any `find` or shell that is used.

Comment: @val0x00ff: “…the above code is pretty much compatible with any `find` or shell that is used.” True, but so is `find … -exec mv {} MYDIR \;`, and that uses less resources than `… -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" MYDIR' _ {} \;`.

Comment: @Scott is right; this is an odd command.  `+` is specified in POSIX anyway.

Answer (score 7):

It's potentially a bit dangerous but

```
cp * destination/
rm *
```

As both cp and rm won't operate on directories without the -r switch.

Comment: Clever, but surely living on the edge

Comment: That has several issues: (1) it copies the files data, so if `destination` is on the same file system, it's going to be a lot less efficient than `mv` that just does a rename. (2) if fails if there are filenames starting with `-` (or have bad consequences, think of a `-t..` file for instance. (3) for symlinks, it copies the target (provided it's a directory) instead of the symlink. (4) it doesn't preserve metadata (5) it breaks hard links...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple 1 line command to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
find ./sourceDir -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs mv -t ./targetDir
```

**Explanation**

1. Find all the files you want at depth 1 only, that are of type files. You can find explanation here.
   https://linux.die.net/man/1/find
2. Pipe that using "| xargs" to mv.
   https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs
3. tell mv where to move the files
   https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv

This 1 liner is fairly portable, and can be run from anywhere in the system as long as you have the sourceDir and targetDir, either as full paths or relative paths.

Comment: You might want to use `xargs -d '\n'` to support filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`mv $(find /my/source/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f) /my/destination/directory`

Move will take a list of arguments, so when you ask `find` to give you everything that is of type "file" within `/my/source/directory`, it will move them one by one to `/my/destination/directory`. If you wanted to include the files in the subdirectories, too, while leaving the directory structure intact, remove `-maxdepth 1` from the above command.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f|awk '{ gsub( "\40", "\\\40"); print}' | xargs -I{} mv {} /path/to/dest/directory/{}
```

Please ensure you are in the current directory where your files to be moved are present while executing the command.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` will find all the files in the folder .

`awk '{ gsub( "\40", "\\\40"); print}'` will replace "space" ( ) with "\space" (`\` ) . `\40` is the octal for "space". This ensures that files with spaces in their names are also included.

`xargs -I{} mv {} /path/to/dest/directory/{}` will capture the piped output as an argument and then `{}` will substitute the argument value i.e., filenames from previous command in `{}` of `mv {} /path/to/dest/directory/{}` source and destination arguments.

This command will ensure that files that has spaces in their names are moved as well.

Comment: I have removed the extra brackets. I was trying out individual commands within bracket since I was also learning the individual command behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest simply doing `mv *.* destination/` with destination/ being the folder you are moving to.

Comment: check out: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Directory names can contain 'dot' and filenames can exclude it (and often do) so `*.*` will move some directories and leave some files, which is not what the asker wanted.

Comment: Sorry but this is completely wrong. It will simply move anything with a dot in its name and not move anything without one. Dots are in no way exclusive to files and they're not required by files either, so this will just move a random selection of files and directories.

Comment: maybe not ideal, but is good enough for me!... though why didn't I think of this.

Answer (score -1):

```
if [ -f "$PATH/$FILE_NAME" ]; then mv "$PATH/$FILE_NAME" "$OTHER_PATH/$FILE_NAME"; fi;
```

Comment: The question says “all the files”.  This will move one file.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't intend to move dotfiles (e.g. ".foobar"), too, you can simply do:

```
mv * /some/destination/
```

If you do, see the above answer with find's -maxdepth.

Comment: The question says “move all the files …, but leave all the sub-directories as they are.”  This will move everything.   When you’re adding a new answer to a six-year-old question that already has seven answers, you might want to glance at them to see whether you have totally overlooked a key condition of the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
mv $(ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{print $9}') ./folder_where_move
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs